# Redirect by mod_rewrite from not existing page to search page by using not existing page name

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

How to make  redirect from not existing page like `http://mydomain.com/category-1/key-word-1/` to search page by using not existing page name like `http://mydomain.com/?search=key word 1` instead of getting 404 page.

Or even probably would be better to put that search results on 404 page?

current lines in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your existing .htaccess file? Are you accessing static files only or does your url get rewritten and handled by some sort of framework?

Comment: added existing lines from .htaccess

Comment: It looks like you are routing all of your requests though an  `index.php` file which is indicative of using a framework to handle your requests in which case doing this with `mod_rewrite` is impossible. You need to override your framework's 404 method/page to make it redirect instead.

Comment: so it is not possible add just other conditions and rules to handle additional rules?

Comment: It is possible to do have conditional rewrites yes, however `.htaccess` has no way of knowing that the page you are looking for doesn't exist because that is determined in your php framework, not the filesystem. The only thing `.htaccess` knows is if the request is being made to a file or folder which exists. This condition is already being handled by your current rules which say "if request is not a file and request is not a folder rewrite to index.php".

Comment: I thought it could catch up if the results is 404 page (after handling all things on index.php) and then if so redirect to search page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35663/discussion-between-bad-wolf-and-marat)